# Compare the data in two tables with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been doing a bit of searching for a while now on a particular problem, but I can't quite find this particular question

I have a rather unusual task to achieve in SQL:

I have two tables, say A and B, which have exactly the same column names, of the following form:

```
id | column_1 | ... | column_n
```

Both tables have the same number of rows, with the same id's, but for a given id there is a chance that the rows from tables A and B differ in one or more of the other columns.

I already have a query which returns all rows from table A for which the corresponding row in table B is not identical, but what I need is a query which returns something of the form:

```
id | differing_column
----------------------
1  | column_1
3  | column_6
```

meaning that the row with id '1' has different 'column_1' values in tables A and B, and the row with id '3' has different 'column_6' values in tables A and B.

Is this at all achievable? I imagine it might require some sort of pivot in order to get the column names as values, but I might be wrong. Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that with a query like this:

```
WITH Diffs (Id, Col) AS (
    SELECT
        a.Id,
        CASE
            WHEN a.Col1 <> b.Col1 THEN 'Col1'
            WHEN a.Col2 <> b.Col2 THEN 'Col2'
            -- ...and so on
            ELSE NULL
        END as Col
    FROM TableOne a
    JOIN TableTwo b ON a.Id=b.Id
)
SELECT Id, Col
WHERE Col IS NOT NULL
```

Note that the above query is not going to return all the columns with differences, but only the first one that it is going to find.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a lot easier than I had anticipated. I have considered the case where rows differ on more than one column, but for now just flagging one column is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `unpivot` -- assuming that the values in the columns are of the same type.

If your data is not too big, I would just recommend using a bunch of `union all` statements instead:

```
select a.id, 'Col1' as column
from a join b on a.id = b.id
where a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col1 is null and b.col1 is not null or a.col1 is not null and b.col1 is null
union all
select a.id, 'Col2' as column
from a join b on a.id = b.id
where a.col2 <> b.col2 or a.col2 is null and b.col2 is not null or a.col2 is not null and b.col2 is null
. . .
```

This prevents issues with potential type conversion problems.

If you don't mind having the results on one row, you can do:

```
select a.id,
       (case when a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col1 is null and b.col1 is not null or a.col1 is not null and b.col1 is null
             then 'Col1;'
             else ''
         end) +
       (case when a.col2 <> b.col2 or a.col2 is null and b.col2 is not null or a.col2 is not null and b.col2 is null
             then 'Col2;'
             else ''
         end) +
       . . .
from a join b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the first block of code does what I need, although I have 29 columns so it requires a lot of typing! Is the null checking needed? I would have thought x <> y would return true if x has a value and y is null...

Comment: @MattG . . . About the NULLs, you thought wrong.  Any such comparison with NULL returns NULL, which is treated as false.

Comment: @MattG Any operation with `NULL` returns a `NULL`. If your columns contain `NULL` values, you need to expand your conditions the way Gordon shows in the conditions in his second example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Gordon, thanks both for this explanation. That would have definitely tripped me up at some point!

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are of the same type, there is a slick method:

```
SELECT id,col
FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B) t1
UNPIVOT (value for col in (column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4)) t2
GROUP BY id,col
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) > 1
```

If you need to handle NULL as a unique value, then use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(value,X)) > 1` with X being a value that doesn't occur in your data